# how can i access this files in Android Emulator Using Command line

Tags: android, root

here

i have rooted emulator so i have access of super user.

i want to access this location in Android Emulator /data/data/com.google.android.location/files to get `cache.wifi and cache.cell file`.

i tried so many times from cmd but i cant found any package of `com.google.android.location` at /data/data.

i performed below steps

```
1 adb shell
2 su
3 cd data
4 cd data
5 ls
```

After 5th command i got lsit of packages which are below.

```
com.android.htmlviewer
com.android.quicksearchbox
com.android.defcontainer
com.android.server.vpn
com.android.music
com.android.providers.applications
com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
com.android.fallback
com.svox.pico
com.android.inputmethod.latin
android.tts
com.android.soundrecorder
com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.gallery
com.android.providers.subscribedfeeds
com.android.providers.drm
com.android.customlocale
com.android.spare_parts
com.android.speechrecorder
com.android.term
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.android.browser
com.android.packageinstaller
com.android.certinstaller
com.android.netspeed
com.android.systemui
com.android.contacts
com.android.protips
com.android.camera
com.android.sdksetup
com.android.calculator2
com.android.development
com.android.gesture.builder
com.example.android.softkeyboard
com.example.android.livecubes
com.example.android.apis
com.android.providers.settings
com.android.settings
com.android.providers.contacts
jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
com.android.phone
com.android.providers.telephony
com.android.launcher
com.android.providers.downloads
com.android.mms
com.android.deskclock
com.android.providers.media
com.android.email
```

There is no package or file of named `com.google.android.location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// I searched a lot and find answer for you

the problem is your are trying in normal avd. see in your post I never find any **com.android.google** package file

just do this with goole api's emulator then you will get it.

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb shell
# cd data/data
# ls
com.google.android.marvin.soundback
com.google.android.marvin.talkback
com.codecarpet.fbconnect.sample
com.android.providers.drm
com.android.email
com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch
com.android.fallback
com.android.gesture.builder
com.android.globalsearch
com.android.htmlviewer
com.android.inputmethod.latin
com.android.launcher
com.google.android.apps.maps
com.android.providers.media
com.android.mms
com.android.music
com.android.netspeed
com.google.android.location `**// here is it**`
jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
com.android.alarmclock
com.android.providers.applications
com.android.browser
com.android.calculator2
com.android.camera
com.android.contacts
com.android.providers.contacts
com.android.customlocale
com.android.development
com.android.providers.downloads
com.android.packageinstaller
com.android.phone
com.svox.pico
com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
com.android.sdksetup
com.android.settings
com.android.providers.settings
com.android.soundrecorder
com.android.spare_parts
com.google.android.street
com.android.providers.telephony
com.android.term
android.tts
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.android.server.vpn
com.google.android.marvin.kickback
com.purpletalk.clique
com.wtso
com.cum.chk
com.habitfactor
com.org.Straxis
ban.card
org.cocos2d
```

Answer (score 0):

try a `find / -name cache.cell`